# Debug what addons IE blocks ( Via group policy)

Tags: group-policy, internet-explorer

I have the policy set to block all unkown addons, but im having issues with getting the right addons in there. This is working now, with exeption of some of the older Citrix access gateway and im looking for some log file where IE logs addons its not allowed to run.

I know the UI triggers and shows a list, but that list is NOT complete. So im hoping for some log file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a real answer to your question, but when users disable add-ons via IE UI the GUID of the add-on is recorded in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Ext\Settings{GUID}.

For reference, the place in Group Policy where you can enable/disable specific add-ons is  Group Policy Editor > User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Internet Explorer > Security Features > Add-on Management > Add-on List. See the help for that Group Policy for instructions on what values to provide to enable/disable add-ons.

I don't know of any log file where IE records which add-ons it has disabled.